# Select ggtheme randomly

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, themes

I would like to draw a ggplot with a random theme (In fact, I want to draw many plots, each with a different theme). Consider the following reproducible example:

```
# Exmple data
df <- data.frame(x = 1:10, y = 1:10)

# Select theme randomly
random_theme <<- sample(c("theme_gray", "theme_bw", "theme_light", "theme_dark", "theme_minimal", "theme_classic"), 1)

# Draw ggplot
ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_line() +
  random_theme            # This line does not work
```

**Question: How can I select a ggtheme randomly?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sice your `random_theme` is a `character` vector, you can use `eval` and then `parse` to parse your theme.

```
library(tidyverse)

ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_line() +
  eval(parse(text = paste0(random_theme, "()")))
```

Or more directly:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_line() +
  eval(parse(text = paste0(sample(c("theme_gray",
                                    "theme_bw", 
                                    "theme_light", 
                                    "theme_dark", 
                                    "theme_minimal", 
                                    "theme_classic"), 1)  , "()")))
```

Comment: Thank you, that's it. I was trying functions such as do.call or get, but none of them worked. Your solution is perfect.

Comment: Parsing constructed expressions is a bit kludgy when you can sample directly from a list of functions.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. It's an approach based on given data (`character`) though.

Comment: If given character, `get` will work. `rt = "theme_dark" ; ggplot(etc) + get(rt)()` works.

Comment: You should put that in your answer too ;) thank you.

Answer (score 11):

Sample from the functions and not the names of the functions. Also, sample returns a list when sampling from anything more complex than a scalar, so you need the first list element. Eg:

```
> sample(c(sqrt, sqrt),2)
[[1]]
function (x)  .Primitive("sqrt")

[[2]]
function (x)  .Primitive("sqrt")
```

So get a random theme function with:

```
random_theme <- sample(c(theme_gray, theme_bw, theme_light, theme_dark, theme_minimal, theme_classic), 1)[[1]]
```

and call it when you plot:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) +geom_line() + random_theme()
```

Resample `random_theme` and plot again to update.

Also, you probably don't need the `<<-` which I guess is a hangover from desperately trying to make something work...

Comment: Also a very nice solution. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 6):

You could do this with `match.fun()`:

```
random_theme = match.fun(sample(c("theme_gray", "theme_bw", "theme_light", "theme_dark", "theme_minimal", "theme_classic"), 1))

ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) +
 geom_line() +
 random_theme()
```

Comment: Thank you, that works as well! As stated above, I was trying do.call and get, but I didn't think about match.fun. Thanks a lot!